# JavaScript RegExp ignore case flag vs global match flag

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a codesample for the flag ignore case. I was expected to receive only one match.

```
var str = "Sample text";
var a = new Array();
a = str.match(/S(am)(p)/i);
```

result

a = [Samp] [am] [p]

I was expected to have a = [Samp]

if you change i flag with g

```
var str = "Sample text";
var a = new Array();
a = str.match(/S(am)(p)/g);
```

surprise (at least for me) the result has only one element

a = [Samp]

Comment: `i` means case insensitive matching.

Comment: The other matches are captured by the capturing groups `()`. `match()` function returns at most only 1 match if no `g` flag, with captured text from index 1.

Comment: I think you need to re-read the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Regex Match Capture is returning whole match, not group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264701/javascript-regex-match-capture-is-returning-whole-match-not-group)

Comment: Regarding the duplicate: the asker there seems to have misunderstandings about how match groups work, but both questions deal with the same behavior of `match()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript regex API is extremely unintuitive as it does all sorts of magic depending on the `g`-flag.

I am just gonna cover how `.match` behaves:

- Without `g`-flag `.match` returns an array of full match plus all the capture groups or `null` in case of no match.
- With `g`-flag `.match` returns an array of all the full matches and capture groups don't make a difference. `null` if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = str.match(/S(am)(p)/i);
```

return first matched string, $1 $2

a = str.match(/S(am)(p)/g);

return array of matched (only one here)

if your string is decalred like that

```
var str = "Sample text Sample text";
```

/g return Samp Samp, it is usefull when your regexp looks like `/S(.m)(p)/g` and  string looks like `"Sample text Simple text";`